# Can I not use multiple Exceptions?

Tags: python

When I try to use multiple exceptions, for some reason I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: default 'except:' must be last
```

Code:

```
try:
    to_address = item["tx"]
    amount_xrp = int(item["tx"]["TakerGets"])/1000000.0
except:
    to_address = item["tx"]
except:
    to_address = "Cancellation"#item["tx"]["TakerPays"]
    amount_xrp = "NA"
```

Comment: putting aside the other confusion here, you shouldn't be using `except` but rather catching specific exceptions, in this case `except KeyError:` looks right to me

Answer (score 1):

The `except:` clause catches any exception.  There's no sense in using it twice.  What would it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not correct Python syntax. You could do the following:

```
try:
    to_address = item["tx"]
    amount_xrp = int(item["tx"]["TakerGets"])/1000000.0

except:
    try:
        to_address = item["tx"]

    except:
        to_address = "Cancellation"#item["tx"]["TakerPays"]
        amount_xrp = "NA"
```

Comment: That is a thing they could do, but it's not at all clear whether it's what they should do, or whether it does anything like what they're trying to achieve. `amount_xrp` is likely to end up unassigned, for example.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess at what you're trying to achieve  here is to have `to_address` be set to `Cancellation` if it's not in `items`, and have `amount_xrp` be set to 'NA' if `to_address` doesn't have a `'TakerGets'` key.

```
to_address = item.get('tx', 'Cancellation') #returns 'Cancellation' if no key 'tx'
amount_xrp = 'NA'

if to_address != 'Cancellation':
    try:
        amount_xrp = int(to_address["TakerGets"])/1000000.0
    except KeyError:
        pass
```